# jQuery foreach values in variables

Tags: jquery

So, I have the following html:

```
<div class="all_names">
    <span class="name" data-name="1">Steve</span>
    <span class="name" data-name="2">Mike</span>
    <span class="name" data-name="3">Sean</span>
    <span class="name" data-name="4">Emily</span>
</div>
<div class="show_names"></div>
```

Then for js:

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.all_names', function(e) {
    var name = jQuery(this).html(); ????    
    var name_number = jQuery(this).data("name");????

    var show_names ='<div class="show" id="'+ name_number + '">'+ name + '<div>';  ????           

    jQuery('.show_names').html(show_names);

}
```

Then the desired end result should be as following:

```
<div class="show_names">
    <div class="show" id="1">Steve<div>   
    <div class="show" id="2">Mike<div>   
    <div class="show" id="3">Sean<div>   
    <div class="show" id="4">Emily<div>   
</div>
```

**Here is my question:**

When the class `all_names` is clicked, I want to save all the names (and corresponding `name number`) into variables.

Then, I want to use these values to load the html portion for individual values as shown in the desired end result.

How do I achieve this? Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The desired end result HTML (IDs now have the values that `data-name` had before) and your description *"I want to save all the names (and corresponding name number) into variables"* have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write following code inside click even of div with class `all_names`. You can use [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate throght all spans with class `.name`. Then can use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to append html to div with class `.show_names`.

```
jQuery( "span.name" ).each(function( index ) {
  var html = '<div class="show" id="'+ jQuery(this).data("name")+ '">'+ jQuery(this).text()+ '</div>';
  $( "div.show_names" ).append(html);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mfLt7/89/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code (building the string of html code out of each span inner texts and its data-name attributes:

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.all_names', function(e) {
    var string = '';
    jQuery(this).find('span').each(function(){
        string += '<div class="show" id="'+ jQuery(this).attr("data-name") + '">'+ jQuery(this).text() + '</div>';
    });
    jQuery('.show_names').html(string);
});
```

By the way - beware using integer as the element's id, it is not advised! If you do have to do this, I recommend you to get acquainted with the methods of css selecting those elements by id:

[How to select an element that has id starting with a digit (css)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938244/how-to-select-an-element-that-has-id-starting-with-a-digit-css/30938366#30938366)