# Can't locate <a> element with all-number id attribute in Playwright ('#56' is not a valid selector)

Tags: typescript, automation, playwright, browser-automation

I want to catch and locate `<a>` element with id attribute.
Possible attributes:

- role
- href
- title
- id
- style
- onclick

I can do it by role and name, but can't do it by id or onclick. The last two would be helpful in future work.

When I try to click on locator located by role and name there's all good:

```
point56Button = this.page.getByRole('button', {
    name: 'Pole 56',
    exact: true,
  });
```

but if do it by id I have
Error: locator.click: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '#56' is not a valid selector.

```
    at query (<anonymous>:3329:41)
    at <anonymous>:3339:7
    at SelectorEvaluatorImpl._cached (<anonymous>:3116:20)
    at SelectorEvaluatorImpl._queryCSS (<anonymous>:3326:17)
    at SelectorEvaluatorImpl._querySimple (<anonymous>:3206:19)
    at <anonymous>:3154:29
    at SelectorEvaluatorImpl._cached (<anonymous>:3116:20)
    at SelectorEvaluatorImpl.query (<anonymous>:3147:19)
    at Object.query (<anonymous>:3361:44)
    at <anonymous>:3319:21
```

Website code:

```
<a role="button" href="#" title="Pole 56" id="56" style="width:104px;height:16px;top:611px;left:668px;text-align:Right;vertical-align:text-bottom;position:absolute;cursor:pointer;padding-top:71px;font-size:13px;color:black;" onclick="RunSubwizard('56',event);"></a>
```

My code to locate an element by id:

```
point56Button = this.page.locator('#56');
```

I want to click on  element locate by id

Expected result: open wizard

Work with locate element by role and name
Didn't work with locate element by id

Answer (score 1):

This is unrelated to Playwright, although the context is useful. The CSS selector error manifests in pure browser code:

```js
document.querySelector("#56");
  // => SyntaxError: Document.querySelector: '#56' is not a valid selector
```

```html
<a id="56"></a>
```

A workaround to handle the all-number id is to use an attribute selector:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('[id="56"]'));
```

```html
<a id="56"></a>
```

If it's not apparent, the Playwright locator will be `this.page.locator('a[id="56"]');`.

Related: [How to select an element that has an ID which begins with a digit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938244/how-to-select-an-element-that-has-an-id-which-begins-with-a-digit)

Comment: Thanks! It's useful tip. In my context this work

Want locate
<a role="button" href="#" title="Pole 56" id="56" style="width:104px;height:16px;cursor:pointer" onclick="RunSubwizard('56',event);"></a>

Do it by locator
point56Button = this.page.locator('a[id="56"]');

Comment: I thought that was pretty apparent, but I've added it into the question to be explicit. Thanks for confirming it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

That's work in my context:

HTML element want to locate

```
<a role="button" href="#" title="Pole 56" id="56" style="width:104px;height:16px;cursor:pointer" onclick="RunSubwizard('56',event);"></a>
```

Do it by locator

```
point56Button = this.page.locator('a[id="56"]');
```